# How can I reference the user's home directory in WIX

Tags: wix

I am creating an installer for an SDK, which includes source code to be compiled by the end-user.

I want my Wix installer to put this in the users' home directory by default, but I can't find the right property name to use.

Answer (score 5):

You could also reference the `HOMEPATH` environment variable with `[%HOMEPATH]`. For more detail about the syntax used for properties, see the [Formatted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) datatype.

Comment: On a related note, there's also `[%HOMEDRIVE]` which you can prefix to get a full path: `[%HOMEDRIVE][%HOMEPATH]`. Alternatively, `$(env.HOMEDRIVE)$(env.HOMEPATH)` can be used.

Comment: ...ignore the last part of my previous comment, the `$(env.)` versions are evaluated at compile time, not install time! And note there's also `[%USERPROFILE]`.

Comment: ...and it turns out that it's possible for `[%HOMEDRIVE][%HOMEPATH]` to be different from `[%USER_PROFILE]`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for `PersonalFolder`.

There is a full list of special folders here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28VS.85%29.aspx#system_folder_properties

Comment: PersonalFolder is the Documents folder for the current user, I'm looking for the user's actual folder. The Documents folder will do though, so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps, for WiX v3.11.2.4516 I have used `USER_FOLDER` like the example below:

```
<Directory Id="USER_FOLDER">
    ...
</Directory>
```

**EDIT**

...having calculated this property with

```
<Property Id="USER_FOLDER" >
    <DirectorySearch Id="userProfileSearch" Depth="0" Path="[%USERPROFILE]" />
</Property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone in the future looking into this, and wondering how to make this [%HOMEPATH] work then hopefully this helps you:

```
<!-- Declare an action which binds the 'user home' to UserFolder 
     (You can replace [%HOMEDRIVE][%HOMEPATH] with [%USERPROFILE], read the difference from internet.) -->
<CustomAction 
     Id='SpecifyUserFolder' 
     Directory='UserFolder'
     Value="[%HOMEDRIVE][%HOMEPATH]" />

<!-- put this before installation process -->
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SpecifyUserFolder" Before="InstallFiles" />
</InstallExecuteSequence> 

<!-- User home then becomes available here, because the ID matches the declared ID in CustomAction above. -->
<Directory Id='UserFolder'>
</Directory>'
```