# %USERPROFILE does not work with WiX

Tags: windows, wix

I am making a setup of my application with WiX. I want to copy/paste an .ini file in the current user folder on Windows (C:\Users\{username})

I saw on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635813/how-can-i-reference-the-users-home-directory-in-wix) that I should use the tag **[%USERPROFILE]**. 
I use it this way :

```
<Directory Id="UserFolder" Name="[%USERPROFILE]">
<Directory/>
```

As a result, a folder [%USERPROFILE] is created in C:\ containing the .ini file. This is not what I want.

Does anyone have an idea how to make it work ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500373/wix-toolset-setting-a-property-to-user-profile-folder-path-and-program-files and http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Environment-variables-into-a-WIX-property-td5412818.html might be of interest to you.  I've never seen [%USERPROFILE], and it looks weird. Cursory check doesn't find it in the Wix docs.  Might not be valid anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @Will I have tried what they mentionned, in vain.

Comment: Any reference to the current user won't be meaningful for per-machine installs.  Are you sure your setup is per-user rather than per-machine?  (And in any case, putting your .ini file directly into the user profile rather than the user's application data folder is the wrong thing to do.  Windows isn't Linux!)

Comment: I need the setup to be per-machine. But this file has to be copied in the USER folder because it stores the session data, another user may have different settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[%USERPROFILE]` is a valid environment variable reference, but I don't think it can be used in this context, as this context isn't [formatted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609). See the [Directory Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368295) for details.

Note that, as mentioned in the comments, `%USERPROFILE%` is likely the wrong place for any files you may want to install. Consider using another [predefined folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905#System_Folder_Properties), such as `AppDataFolder`, `LocalAppDataFolder`, or `PersonalFolder`.

If you go with [`PersonalFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370806), I believe you can just use that instead:

```
<Directory Id="PersonalFolder"> ... </Directory>
```

If there is no satisfactory predefined folder property, you can use either a [type 51](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368237) or a [type 35](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368093) custom action (depending on whether you schedule it before or after CostFinalize to set the run time value of your folder to `[%USERPROFILE]`. Those custom actions will format the value they use. Make sure to use an ALL-CAPS name so that it can be set at run time. For example, if the directory is called USERPROFILEFOLDER:

```
<SetDirectory Id="USERPROFILEFOLDER" Value="[%USERPROFILE]"/>
<!-- or -->
<SetProperty Id="USERPROFILEFOLDER" Value="[%USERPROFILE]"/>
```

(And don't forget to schedule the action somewhere.)

Comment: Thank you I think I will change my soft to read in LocalAppDataFolder instead of USER folder then.